# Installing Xamarin on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, android, xamarin

I wanted to install Xamarin on WinXP Pro SP3 (32bit) and used the automatic installer but it said the Windows version was not correct so I went on and tried to install all components manually. I installed:

- installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe (Android SDK)
- gtk-sharp-2.12.21.msi
- mono-android-4.6.00049.msi
- XamarinStudio-4.0.msi

Now, when I open a solution in Xamarin Studio and try to compile it, I get error:

`Error: The Android SDK could not be found, please set the path to it in the Xamarin.Android SDKs settings panel. (TaskyAndroid_Starter)`

I've tried to find the path to Xamarin.Android but have no idea if it is installed at all.
How can I fix this?

Comment: If the installer is not for your environment, maybe that's a hint to stop installing. If you want to push through, try procmon where you filter based on the process .exe name only. That might tell you where in the folder structure it is looking for the file.

Comment: You installed everything except the Android SDK you might want to do that.

Comment: You are trying to install an Android App (Xamarin, cross platform app language) inside Android on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the path to Xamarin.Android but to the Android SDK you installed via installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe.

On my machine the Android SDK is in the directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK needs the Java SDK to work correctly.
Just download and install the Java SDK to the default path, run the Xamarin automatic installer again and it should pick up both and continue.

Answer (score 0):

This likely has to do with .Net 4.5 not being supported on Windows XP.
You can try installing with the latest versions from the link below:

http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-4.0.8.msi
http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.07004.msi

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has dropped support for Windows XP

> The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. Xamarin.Forms Windows support requires Windows 8.1, and Xamarin.Forms UWP support requires Windows 10.

Source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements